# No Internet Alert box in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, webview, alert

I just started learning Kotlin,I am currently working on a WebView based app and I need to show a alert box if Internet is not available after the app is open. How can I do that in Kotlin?

Note: I already have checked through many Stack Overflow questions, but all the answers are for java and not Kotlin.
Also, I'm just a beginner, So Please write down answer in simple way so I can understand. Sorry for Bad English

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out there's an example of how to do it with kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private fun checkConnectivity() {
        val manager = this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = manager.activeNetworkInfo

        if (null == activeNetwork) {
            val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            // set message of alert dialog
            dialogBuilder.setMessage("Make sure that WI-FI or mobile data is turned on, then try again")
                // if the dialog is cancelable
                .setCancelable(false)
                // positive button text and action
                .setPositiveButton("Retry", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                    recreate()
                })
                // negative button text and action
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                    finish()
                })

            // create dialog box
            val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
            // set title for alert dialog box
            alert.setTitle("No Internet Connection")
            alert.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            // show alert dialog
            alert.show()
        }
    }
```

Also add add this permissions to Manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

This should be enough to show a dialog if there's no Internet Connection in your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.ConnectivityManager

open class ConnectionCheck:BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
            connectivityReceiverListener!!.onNetworkConnectionChanged(
                isConnectedOrConnecting(
                    context!!
                )
            )
        }
    }

    private fun isConnectedOrConnecting(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connMgr = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connMgr.activeNetworkInfo
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
    }

    interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
        fun onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected: Boolean)
    }

    companion object {
        var connectivityReceiverListener: ConnectivityReceiverListener? = null
    }
}
```

This is internet connectivity activity. In every activity that you want to check internet connection, that activity should extend `ConnectionCheck.ConnectivityReceiverListener`.

Don't forget to put 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in manifest.

Comment: I didn't got it. Should I create a different class for it or use it in AppCompatACtivity?

Comment: Yes, create new class @AndersonSpencer

Comment: I'm receiving "Classifier 'ConnectivityReceiverListener' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here" Error. Can't I do this withour creating a separate class and just using showAlert while there's no internet connection?

Comment: Add  override fun onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected: Boolean) {
       
    }  @AndersonSpencer